# Why can't we add BigDecimal to TreeSet ?

Tags: java, collections

I read somewhere that we can't add BigDecimal to TreeSet because it incorrectly implements compareTo method , e.g. for 9.0 and 9.00 , it will return 0 , although using equals method it will return false. This seems to be the reason. Can someone explain in a bit more detail ?

Comment: I would venture to say BigDecimal has it's quirks, and you should use a different class, if not `Double` then one of your own,

Comment: You can use a `TreeSet<BigDecimal>`, you just beed to be aware that adding `1.0` and `1.00` will only add one value to your TreeSet. That may or may be acceptable depending on your use case.

Comment: Actually, this isn't a duplicate because in the case of using `TreeSet` there is an easy solution, use a constructor with a custom comparator: `TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`

Answer (score 2):

`equals()` in this case will return false because their precision is different. `compareTo()` will return 0 because the "value" are the same.

Comment: Please select as answer if it solved your problem.